# MongoDB to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, mongodb, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a project where I want to scrape a website that produces content periodically, store the content in a MongoDB cluster, preview the documents in a chrome extensions.

First two step are completed, the website is being scraped through a python script (automated through GitHub actions) and dumped in a MongoDB cluster.

I am having trouble going through the third step, what is an optimal way to fetch the data from MongoDB and preview you them in an extension. Could this be achieved using Python? Could this be done client-side Javascript? or is Node.JS needed here?

Any ideas are welcome, excuse me for a vague question but I have ran out of resources.

Comment: Extensions can't do it directly. Either enable an HTTP port in your db and use `fetch` in the extension or write an additional app and connect to it from the extension by using nativeMessaging API.

Comment: You will need a server. Doesn't matter which language as long as it has a MongoDB client. Then in your extension you will send an HTTP request to your server to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need your Chrome extension to call a service/server somewhere else. Luckily, if all you need to do is get a document back that is very easy to do!

You can use various programming languages or even a hosted service like MongoDB Atlas. Then make a call to whatever page/api you've made inside your chrome extension.

While you can use a lot of different [programming languages and frameworks](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/) MongoDB has some easy to follow tutorials:

- [Python with PyMongo](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/python/pymongo-tutorial)
- [Node.JS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/)
- [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/tutorial/connect-to-your-cluster/) (a hosted service with a free tier, also has Python, Node.JS directions)